# Fourier transform of complicated function

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I am looking for a way to find the Fourier transform of the function $f(x) = x^{ax}$. The issue is I don't know where to begin the problem, is there a way to simply the above function and find Fourier tranform? Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Any typo? You say exponential.

Comment: @Tim I don't know whether the function has any specific name, but plotting this shows exponential behaviour in the large $x$ value. Hence calling it complicated exponential function. I rewrite the title by removing the word "exponential"

Comment: Unless $a=0$, that function does not belong to any class on which the Fourier transform can be meaningfully defined. In short, what you are looking for does not exist. For a simpler example, note that you cannot Fourier transform the real exponential $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be mentioned that there exists a stable probability  $\mu(dy)$ of parameter 1 (with the same Levy measure as the Cauchy distribution but restricted to $(-\infty,0)$ such that
$$x^{ax}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{xy}\mu(dy).$$ This $\mu$ is called a Landau distribution and is described in Wikipedia.

I do not understand well the question:'find the Fourier transform of $x^{ax}$' since clearly this density has no Fourier transform in the ordinary sense. If it is in the sense of a more general theory, like Schwartz distributions, I am not competent but guess that the result could have something to do with the density of the Landau distribution.